# Count Function in having clause not working

Tags: mysql, sql

```
    SELECT Book_Title, Publisher_Name, Book_Type, Author_Last, Author_First

    FROM Book,  Author, Publisher, Wrote

    WHERE Author.Author_Num=Wrote.Author_Num

    AND Wrote.Book_Code=Book.Book_Code

    AND Book.Publisher_Code=Publisher.Publisher_Code

    GROUP BY Wrote.Book_Code, Book_Title,  Book_Type, Publisher_Name, Author_Last, Author_First 

    HAVING COUNT (Wrote.Book_Code)=2;
```

Goal: List the title, publisher name, type, and author names of each book that has two authors.

When i run this query, i got empty rows. Anybody help why it happens?

Comment: Please include sample data, table definitions and expected output in your question

Comment: List the title, publisher name, type, and author names of each book that has two authors.This is my Question

Comment: @tiwa, Because "COUNT (Wrote.Book_Code) = 2" is false here.

Comment: NO, Its not false, there are some values whose count is 2

Comment: No, its not, bcz there are some values whose count is 2

Comment: `"When i run this query, i got empty rows"` means there's no problem with your syntax. We can not know the rest, cause we don't have any data.

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, standard `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: You are grouping by book title and author name, an author hasn't written the same book twice. Fix your group by.

Comment: `book_code` is unique for each book. So you need to `group by book_code` only

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Book_Title, Publisher_Name, Book_Type, Author_Last, Author_First

FROM Book,  Author, Publisher, Wrote

WHERE Author.Author_Num=Wrote.Author_Num

AND Wrote.Book_Code=Book.Book_Code

AND Book.Publisher_Code=Publisher.Publisher_Code

GROUP BY Wrote.Book_Code

HAVING COUNT (Wrote.Book_Code)=2;
```

Comment: If i grouping only by book_code, then it gives error that book_title cannot be specified as aggregate function